# Нужно сделать таблицу из 3-х столбцов - рекомендательную систему

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Есть список cо значениями(id разных курсов) - он будет первым столбиком в таблице из 3-х колонок

Например:

```
course = [515, 572, 570, 551, 490, 515, 566, 551, 489, 551, 566]
```

Есть словарь, который состоит из двух популярных пар этих курсов и рейтинга этой пары
Например:

```
{(551, 566): 797,
 (515, 551): 417,
 (489, 551): 311,
 (523, 551): 304,
 (566, 794): 290,
 (489, 515): 286,
 (490, 566): 253,
 (490, 551): 247,
 (570, 752): 247,
 (569, 572): 216,
 (515, 523): 213}
```

Нужно сделать таблицу/датафрейм, где 1-я колонка будет состоять из списка курсов, 2-я и 3-я колонки будут заполняться как "курс для рекомендаций №1"(самый популярный) и "курс для рекомендаций №2"(второй по популярности)

По идее нужна функция, в которую будет подаваться id курса, а возвращается 2 курса, с которым поданный на вход курс чаще всего попадался. Если курс поданный на вход функции есть в ключе словаря - добавляем запись в список и возвращаем 2 самых частотных значения. Если нет, то нужно рекомендовать самые популярные курсы в словаре. Подойдет любое решение, не обязательно что я описал

Что-то вроде этого наверно должно получиться но это не точно:)

```
def recommendations(course_id):
    recommendation_list = []
    for i in popular_couple.keys():
        if i[0] == course_id:
            recommendation_list.append((i, popular_couple[i]))
        if i[1] == course_id:
            recommendation_list.append((i, popular_couple[i]))
        else:
            return popular_couple[0]
        return recommendation_list
```

Например, если на вход функции подается id 551, то функция должна в словаре взять пару этого числа - т.е. 566 и положить куда-то(в список как вариант), далее во второй строке взять 515 и добавить это число в список, после 3-я строка добавить в список 489, после 523, из пятой строки добавлять нечего и т.д. после посчитать кол-во одинаковых значений и выдать топ 2 значения. Нужно счетчик еще добавить похоже. В общем суть я понял что нужно, а как реализовать это пока нет

Comment: Очень интересное задание. А вы сами что-то попробовали сделать? Пока не выглядит как вопрос, а скорее ТЗ для фриланс биржи.

Comment: Это одно из заданий (по проекту) по учебе на дата аналитика, наработки есть такие(добавил), но что-то тут не так, пока не разобрался, вот решил попросить помощи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то можно так (принимая во внимание, что курсы отсортированы по популярности в исходном словаре):

```
import pandas as pd

course = [515, 572, 570, 551, 490, 515, 566, 551, 489, 551, 566]
suggestions = {(551, 566): 797,
 (515, 551): 417,
 (489, 551): 311,
 (523, 551): 304,
 (566, 794): 290,
 (489, 515): 286,
 (490, 566): 253,
 (490, 551): 247,
 (570, 752): 247,
 (569, 572): 216,
 (515, 523): 213}

df = pd.DataFrame(course, columns=["course"])
df["rec"] = df["course"].apply(lambda x: [y for k in suggestions.keys() if x in k
                                          for y in list(k) if y!= x][:2])
```

df:

```
    course         rec
0      515  [551, 489]
1      572       [569]
2      570       [752]
3      551  [566, 515]
4      490  [566, 551]
5      515  [551, 489]
6      566  [551, 794]
7      551  [566, 515]
8      489  [551, 515]
9      551  [566, 515]
10     566  [551, 794]
```